# MySQL query result not reflecting values in database after query is executed once

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am working on a PyQT5 application with part of it being a table that displays movie ratings in a QTableWidget. When I add a movie to the database, I clear the old table and run a new select query to get the ten most recent movies logged. This query works correctly the first time, but fails every time afterwards. Each time after the first add, the select query just returns the 10 entries from the first time the query was executed instead of returning movies logged since then. What's confusing me is that if I run the query in MySQL workbench, it runs correctly every time. It's only when the entries are passed to my application that things go wrong. Here is the refresh method that is run after an entry is added:

```py
def refreshLastTen(self):
        #Refreshes the table of recently watched movies after a new entry is added or a change
        print('Refreshing Last10 Table')
        self.LastTenTable.clearContents()

        #When adding one new movie, the refresh works fine. Anything more than that, the result from the first add is returned every time
        sql = "SELECT * FROM log ORDER BY LOG_MOVIE_DATE desc LIMIT 0, 10" #Selects top 10 results from the table
        cursor = dbConnection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql)
        myresult = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()

        for row_number, row_data in enumerate(myresult):    #Adds data from select statement to the table
            for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.LastTenTable.setItem(row_number, column_number,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
```

For example, I add the movie "Test 1" at the current date (theoretically the most recently watched) to the database and the refresh method returns the following:
[image: Result after First Add]

After this, I add another movie "Test 2" at the current date and instead of returning "Test 2" and "Test 1" as the most recent 2 movies in the list, the same result from the first query is returned again. This continues no matter how many more movies you add. As stated before, if you were to then run the same query in MySQL workbench, it would correctly return "Test 2" and "Test 1" as the two most recent entries. Does anyone have any ideas of what could be happening?

***Edit 1:** Here is the code used in my insert method to add a movie to the database:

```
if self.validateSubmission() == True:
            sql = "INSERT INTO log (LOG_MOVIE_TITLE, LOG_MOVIE_DATE, LOG_MOVIE_RATING, LOG_MOVIE_GENRE, LOG_MOVIE_LOCATION, LOG_MOVIE_COMMENTS) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
            vals = [self.titleVal.text(), self.dateVal.date().toString('yyyy-MM-dd'), self.ratingVal.currentText(), self.genreVal.currentText(), self.locationVal, self.commentVal.toPlainText()] 
            cursor = dbConnection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql, vals)
            dbConnection.commit()
            cursor.close()
            dbConnection.close()
```

***Edit 2:** Here is a screenshot from MySQL Workbench showing the select query working:
[image: Query result in MySQL Workbench]

***Edit 3:** Now I am wondering if it has to do with how I am handling the dbConnection. The refreshLastTen method is in the app's main page class whereas the add happens in an add form class. Each class has dbConnection explicitly defined like this:

```
dbConnection = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="pwd",
    database="moviesheet"
)
```

I am not sure if this causes a disconnect or collision of some sort. I added the following to close the connection in the add form class after the add is done just in case:

```
dbConnection.close()
```

One other oddity that I noticed is that if I run the query in the add form class after the add, it returns the correct result. It seems like it might just be related to the main window class.

Comment: Are you calling `dbConnection.commit()` when you add the new row?

Comment: @Barmar Yes I am. I'll add the code I used to add the entry to the DB to my post

Comment: Maybe they're not the most recent. Do you see them if you remove LIMIT 0, 10?

Comment: @Barmar I am positive that they are the most recent. The other "real" entries in my testing DB are from 2019 and the two test values I entered above are the only ones from 2020. I will add a screenshot of the query running in MySQL Workbench where it works correctly.